# reCaptcha intermittent failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, recaptcha

### reCaptcha Failures

We are using [recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) and it works great...most of the time. The issue is that the reCaptcha will suddenly just fail for a random amount of time before starting to accept requests again. We haven't been able to pin-point the root cause of the issue.

### Additional Information

- The recaptcha analytics say that we do not have enough traffic to provide data with regards to success\fail rates, spam index etc.
- We have verified that our API keys both private and public are correct and in the right order. We went as far as changing these to ensure the keys weren't the issue
- Another anomaly we are seeing is now that one of our users is in the US, they have a 100% failure rate which they did not in the Philippines. Additionally, they can telnet to the API.
- Running rails 4.2.6 with ruby 2.3.3
- This affects all our Ubuntu and osX users when it happens.

### Suggestions?

I am hoping someone can point us in the right direction as this has become a major issue and affects our staging environment (we are pre-launch) and we are out of ideas (it's been months).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Analysis

After deep analysis and trailing the HTTP logs, the root cause is that the rails [Recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) library just flat out doesn't make calls to the Google Recaptcha API at times.

---

### Solution

We eventually gave up trying to figure out how to fix this and we decided we'll just integrate with the API directly via rails [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) and would also grant us full control.

As soon as we quickly whipped up the integration (half an hour including testing), all Recaptcha requests are being made to the API and are behaving as expected.